# printf and custom class

Tags: c++, printing, visual-studio-2012

I have my own class that represents a custom string class. I'm using VS2012RC. I have overloaded some operators of my class CustomString.

Here's some code:

```
CustomString::CustomString(string setstr)
{           
    str = setstr;
}

CustomString::operator const char *()
{   
    return (this->str.c_str());
}

CustomString &CustomString::operator = (char *setstr)
{
    str = setstr;
    return *this;
}
```

I can define my object and use it like this:

```
CustomString str = "Test string";
```

and i can print the result as:

```
printf(str);

printf((string)(str).c_str());

printf((string)(str).data());

printf("%s\n",(string)(str).c_str());

printf("%s\n",(string)(str).data());
```

And there is not any error.

But if i use it like this:

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

There is an exception in msvcr110d.dll (error in memory access)

Why **printf(str)** is ok, but **printf("%s\n",str)** is not ok?

How can i modify my code to use **printf("%s\n",str)** ?

...

After hours of googling, I found that explict cast (string), static_cast (str) and _str() method are add a null-terminated chars: '\0';

i've modified my code as:

```
printf("%s\n",str + '\0');
```

and it's worked!

Is there any way to modify my custom constructor to add a null-terminated string and pass a correct value with null-terminated chars to get working the following code:

```
printf("%s\n",str);
```

Comment: The modification you have used is only working by sheer luck. Passing a class object in a ... results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't (at least not in a portable way). `printf` looks at the object passed as parameter and treats it as a `%s`, which is a char array. You run into undefined behavior. Also, the parameters passed to `printf` are, sort of say, type-less.

> Why printf(str) is ok?

Because the first parameter is types, and is a `const char*`. The implicit cast is made via your operator. The rest of the parameters don't behave the same.

I'd use `cout` instead, and overload `operator << (ostream&, const CustomString&)`.

#### Don't do this:

I said you can't, *in a portable way*. For a class like

```
class CustomString
{
   char* str;
   //...
};
```

that might work, because of how classes are represented in memory. But, again, it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: Your example using `char*` is not correct. The error is the same.

Comment: @user1616375 I told you not to do it!

Comment: ok, could you explain me this: I tried `printf("%s\n",str + '\0');` and  it's ok.  Is there any way to modify my custom constructor to add a null-terminated string and pass a correct value with null-terminated chars? Is it a correct way?

Comment: @user1616375 sure. That's a semi-colon.

Comment: Is it possible to make working `printf("%s\n",str);` by adding `'+\0'` to another code place?

Comment: @user1616375 NO! What you are trying to achieve is not only not possible, but illegal. By definition. You're telling `printf` to expect a null-terminate char array, but you provide something else.

Comment: And there is no another legal or unlegal way to construct `str` as a null-terminated char array and make working code `printf("%s\n",str);`  Am i right?

Comment: @user1616375 no, because `printf` doesn't do any work on the parameters.

Comment: @user1616375 I just read your edit to the question. Don't do it. Find a proper way. That's undefined behavior. It might not always work, it might crash.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `printf`, its more C-like than C++. Instead, use `iostream`s, which provide a facility for you to format your own custom classes and send the to a file or stdout.

Here's a quick (untested) example that might work for you:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const CustomString& str)
{ 
    os << str.data();
    return os; 
}
```

and you'd print your custom string to stdout by doing something like

```
CustomString str;
// put some text in the custom string, then:
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

printf is defined as

```
int printf(char const *fmt, ...)
```

passing a class or structure to a ... argument list has undefined behaviour and may work or crash, or just do something random (I've seen all 3) depending on the class and the compiler.

```
printf(str)
```

requires a char *, and the compiler finds you have an appropriate casting operator, so it invokes it. Note that this is pretty dodgy as you have no idea if str might or might not have a % in it.

So, you to do want `printf("%s", str)` but as you have said, that doesn't work. Some compilers will give you a warning (though 'warning: This will crash' as produced by gcc isn't, in my opinion, terribly well thought out), so you have to force it to be cast to a string. So, your best solution is to explicitly cast it yourself,

```
printf("%s", static_cast<char const *>(str));
```

I'm not sure how much code all of the examples you've got there would require, as most of them are going to involve constructing a std::string from your custom string, then outputting it, then deleting the std::string.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `printf("%s\n", str.c_str());`. `%s` expects a char array and you gave it a `CustomString` object which is something different. You have to get char array from the string by calling `c_str()` function.