# Format specifier for vector<Vec3b> when using printf

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to fetch, let us, say second pixel in buf and print using printf:

```
vector<Vec3b> buf;
/* code that fills buf , I used push_back */
printf("%WHAT", buf[1])
```

I can print these values using cout something like this:

```
    LineIterator it(img, Point(1,1), Point(20,20), 8);

    vector<Vec3b> buf;   

    for(int i=0; i<it.count; i++)
    {
    buf.push_back( Vec3b(*it) ); /* code that fills buf , I used push_back */
    it++;
    }
    cout << Mat(buf[1]) << endl;
```

But I just want to do this using printf.

The cout statement gives me three values, each corresponding to R, G and B.

What should I place for WHAT in my printf? i.e what is the format specifier here?

Comment: Do you want a c solution or a c++ solution?

Comment: @Ben Basically I want to do FFT on the image data. The FFT routine is based on C and expects a pointer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069623/printf-and-custom-class, and since Vec doesn't have an `operator const char *()` built in you can't pass it even as the first argument of printf. If you must use printf (why?), you could inherit from Vec and provide an `operator const char *()`, but that as very limited as discussed in the linked question.

Comment: @gpuguy, instead of a 3rd party fft-lib (in c) , you could just try opencv's [dft](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft).  also, thinking of your original image, it's all a grayscale problem only, right ? (not color pixels)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's no straightforward way to do so. there are overloaded  <<  operators in opencv, but no c solution (why do you even want this?)

you will have to do it all manually:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<buf.size(); i++)
{
   Vec3b v = buf[i];
   printf("[%d %d %d] ", v[0], v[1], v[2] );
}
printf("\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

You wont be able to just use it with printf like that because its not of a standard type. I think you should write a function to print this type for you, for example something like this:

```
void printForMe(vector<Vec3b> buf)
{
    for (auto &vec : buf)
    {
        cout << vec[0] << " " << vec[1] << " " vec[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can then also edit how your format will appear.

This would be even easier if OpenCv's `MatX` class had an overload for `operator<<` but it doesn't so you will need to make this yourself.