# Strings with C++

Tags: c++, string

Each time a program in C++ I remember the meme "of all the possible utensils that could have been invented to eat rice with, how did two sticks win out". 
So let me explain the problem. I want create a class string that act exactly how the strings of visual basic.

```
class kstring
{
    char *value;
    public:
    kstring(char *val)
    {
        value=val;
    }
    kstring operator+(kstring *val)
    {
        //some code here that works
    }

    kstring &operator=(kstring s2)
    {
        value=s2.value;
        return *this;
    }

};
```

So that is all...
The creator function allow the decleration similar to VB :

```
 kstring s="Hello World";
```

the other things are just a bit weird;
Let's try with a printf():

```
 printf("%s\n",s); //I prefear printf as cout because more redeable
```

It works only if the private "**char *value**" get declared as first place. Of course **s** is a pointer, and nobody knows at what point for. So the compilator (code block), fortunately read it as char array. But I do not know if this get done with each compilator and ambient, if is right do it in practice, if there is some better way to define it, such the vb instruction "Default".
Second when get assigned =

```
 kstring s,s2;
 s="try ";
 s2="again";
 s=s+s2;

 printf("%s\n",s);
```

inside the function in debug, it combines exactly "try again" but the printf show just the address, so my assignment function does not work; Some suggests to do an easy class for deal with strings?

Comment: why don't you use [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) from standard library?

Comment: For assignment you must implement [assignment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)) with `const char*` as a parameter. But `std::string` is "standard string", and is good enough for most cases. In printf use `s.c_str()`. Once you adopt a new idea it is easy to use it.

Comment: possibly helpful: [printf and custom class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12069623/2372759)

Comment: of course your pointer just returns a pointer, if you add them. 1) store the string, not just the pointer. in operator+, concat the 2nd string to the first one, override operator const char*() to be able to printf it etc

Comment: "Of course `s` is a pointer" No, it isn't. It is a `kstring`. Anyway, use `std::cout` and overload the appropriate operator. There are tons of posts on how to do that.

Comment: This `kstring` class is one stick. Not much use for eating rice.

Comment: I don't do it for work. Each time I programe in c/c++ if it is not a math function, it need something like two days for debug a function. With vb.net, in two days I wrote the whole program  And than you can never be sure if it work or there is some weird bug, such a free() or delete forget. Or a pointer instead a value and so on. The truth a c program needs at least 1 .000 .000 user to get right debugged.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend learning to use `std::string`.  It is not perfect (in fact it has many flaws), but it *is* what everyone else is using, and it has already been written.

As with any C++ class, you need to worry about memory management.  That is, does the class own the pointer it is passed, or does it just assume that the pointed to memory will outlive the object referring to it.  I strongly recommend the class should own the pointer.

So the constructor will need to become:

```
kstring::kstring(const char* c)
{
    const auto len = strlen(c);
    value = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(value,len);
}
```

The assignment operator will also need a similar change.  Now you need to write a destructor (to free the memory), and a copy constructor (to create copies).  You also should probably add a move constructor, and a move assignment operator.  You can save all this complexity by assuming that the memory always outlives the class - but a) I don't see how you write `operator +`, b) it makes things much harder for your callers.

`operator +` should be an external function (with two arguments) that may need to be a friend of the class (but needn't be if you write `operator +=` as a member).

You cannot pass a class object to `printf`.  Sorry - it's just undefined behaviour.  You got (un)lucky with your compiler.  So you'll need to define a function which converts a `kstring` back to `const char *`.  The `std::string` version is called `c_str()` - you could use that name, or another one.

You should also seriously consider allowing a `len` function, and indexing.

Comment: I don't understand why OP would have to worry about memory management if the string is just pointing to a string literal.

Comment: That is one example of being able to assume the pointer outlives the class (or more precisely the pointed-to memory outlives the object referring to the memory).  However, that is not going to be true for `operator +`

Comment: Apologies. I had missed `operator+`. That changes everything.

Comment: Exactly what I need to read. What ever hold me to use c / c++ was exactly the strings. I need them a lot, for compose queries sql, save data and so on. What I need was an absolutly standard class to include in my code. So if I use a std library it must be so standard as stdio.h or stdlib.h, that every c compiler has. I tried a lot of them, cstring, string, string.h, but I do not know which I must include. You tell me that #include <string.h> is going to work in every compiler?

Comment: `#include <string.h>` will work - but it will include the C standard library functions (`strcpy` etc).  What you need is `#include <string>`.  It won't work in a Fortran compiler, but it has worked in every C++ compiler I have used in the last 20 years, and if it *doesn't* work - it isn't a C++ compiler according to the international standard.